# How do I populate one select from a choice in another select using jquery and a json array

Tags: jquery, json, select, selection, populate

Here is my selects and a json array I could use to populate the second div based on a choice.

I want to erase the second select options first, then populate the options and set the selected value to the first item

```
<select name="select1" id="select1" class="form-control">
    <option value="2">Theme 1</option>
    <option value="1">Theme 2</option>
    <option value="0">unnamed theme</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2" class="form-control">
    <option value="49">Products</option>
</select>
```

json array (created from database values using PHP to echo it out)

```
{"2":{"49":"Products"},"1":{"48":"Product 48","50":"Opportunity","51":"Enroll"},"0":{"52":"Discover product 52","53":"Moringa Support","54":"Product 54","55":"product 55"}}
```

Comment: Clearly you posted this question to post the solution you already came up with, which is fine, but your issue seems too localized for the solution to be of much use to others. IMHO, the solution needs to be more abstract for this to be useful to others

Comment: Your code does not have to be complex to perform complex tasks. My comment was honestly meant to help you understand that. Your code was written to solve *your specific issue* and it reflects that, for example, look at the structure of your JSON, the function depends on this specific structure yet that structure only has meaning to you and would be lost on others a more reusable structure might be something like `{"options":[{"value":"someValue", "text":"someText"}]}`  see what I mean? That might be useful to others with a similar problem

Comment: But I guess I can't expect you to understand such a concept when you use `loopCounter` to keep track of a value in a `.each()` loop that *already has access to that same value via the `index` variable*, declares all their variables in the global scope for no reason at all, and writes twice the code needed to solve a simple problem then posts that code online with a "hey, look what I made" mindless grin ;)

Comment: I added an answer below to show you what I mean, hopefully you will take it as a fellow coder honestly attempting to help you and not react out of spite as your comment above indicates you might, either way I hope it helps you learn. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The below is how I would do this.

Essentially it works like this:

- on your first select add the class `select-master`
- add a data attribute `select-info` whose value is the name of the variable that holds the needed JSON
- add a data attribute `select-slave` whose value is the selector to target the second select box
- attach an event handler to any select with the class `select-master`
- when the `select-master` changes, use the selected value to get the options from the JSON, get the second select, populate it with options

**Note** that I have changed the structure of your JSON. I did this so that the structure would have meaning.

```js
$('.select-master').change(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     var val = $this.val();
     var possibleSelections =window[$this.data('select-info')]; // get the JSON for this box, you could store the JSON in the data attribute itself but this method makes it easier to use the same JSON for multiple boxes easily if needed
     var $slave = $($this.data('select-slave')).html(''); // get the selector for the other select box, find the box, and clear it's contents all in one go
     var selection = possibleSelections[val];
     if(selection){
         $.each(selection.options,function(i,option){
             var selected = i == 0 ? 'selected' : '';
             $slave.append('<option selected="'+selected+'" value="'+option.value+'">'+option.text+'</option>');
         });
     }
});

var selections = {
  "0": {
    options: [{
      value: 52,
      text: "Discover product 52"
    }, {
      value: 53,
      text: "Moringa Support"
    }, {
      value: 54,
      text: "Product 54"
    }, {
      value: 55,
      text: "product 55"
    }]
  },
  "1": {
    options: [{
      value: 48,
      text: "Product 48"
    }, {
      value: 50,
      text: "Opportunity"
    }, {
      value: 51,
      text: "Enroll"
    }]
  },
  "2": {
    options: [{
      value: 49,
      text: "Products"
    }]
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="select1" id="select1" class="form-control select-master" data-select-slave="#select2" data-select-info="selections">
  <option value="2">Theme 1</option>
  <option value="1">Theme 2</option>
  <option value="0">unnamed theme</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2" class="form-control">
  <option value="49">Products</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @DamonHogan  Adding any possible values you want from the database is as simple as calling `var selections = <?php echo  $selections; ?>` when generating the page html or really any other method you choose. The point being that `selections` is a variable and can be set however you like. All of my points are still valid your method is still full of too many flaws to point out in a comment. This is a better solution, even if you did downvote it out of spite. Happy coding ;)